# Проценты на JS как делается?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть

```
<div class="базовая цена">150$</div> 
<div class="Акционная цена">130$</div>
```

Я напишу базовую цену и акционную, мне нужно получить сперва цифру из div и потом процент выгоды, например 27%

Comment: Что не получилось у вас? document.querySelector 2х тэгов в переменные, делите одно на другое, вот вам и процент

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, именование классов на кириллице не является лучшей практикой, хоть и возможно.

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то делается это так:

```js
//получаем из HTML значение базовой и акционной цены
let basePrice = document.querySelector('.base-price').innerHTML,
    salePrice = document.querySelector('.sale-price').innerHTML;

//убираем лишние знаки и приводим значение к integer
basePrice = parseInt(basePrice.replace(/\D+/, ''), 10);
salePrice = parseInt(salePrice.replace(/\D+/, ''), 10);

//рассчитываем процент скидки
let discountPercent = (100 - (salePrice*100/basePrice)).toFixed(2);

//отображаем значение
document.querySelector('.sale-discount').innerHTML = `${discountPercent}%`;
```

```html
<div class="base-price">150$</div>
<div class="sale-price">130$</div>
<div>Discount: <span class="sale-discount">0</span>
```

Надеюсь помог вам разобраться.

Comment: Спасибо вам , сделал